# Gradient Over Video?

Tags: video, sass

I'm having trouble making a background video in my website, and I want to add a gradient over it like the one in the picture below. (Obviously you can't see the video moving, so here's [the link](http://themenectar.com/demo/salient-corporate-2/). It's a WP theme.)

[image: Gradient over video]

I have the video already and I just need to add the gradient.

Any suggestions on how to do this?

Here's my code:

(It's a mix of HTML and Pug) Index.pug file:

```html
    //- Video background
    .section
        h1 Together We Build Dreams
        .video-container
            <video autoplay loop muted>
                <source src="video.mp4" type="video/mp4">
            </video>
```

Style.scss file:

```css
.video-container {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    content: ' ';
    z-index: 2;
    backface-visibility: hidden;
    background: #3452ff;
    background: linear-gradient(135deg,#3452ff 0%,#ff1053 100%);
    opacity: 0.8;
}

.section {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    overflow: hidden;
    
    h1 {
        text-align: center;
        font-size: 4rem;
        color: white;
        padding: 20px;
        margin: 15px;
        z-index: 1;
    }
}
```

P.S. If you need more information, please tell me how I can improve and edit it. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please add HTML and CSS.

```
<div class="bg-overlay"></div>
```

```css
.bg-overlay {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  content: ' ';
  z-index: 2;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  background: #3452ff;
  background: linear-gradient(135deg,#3452ff 0%,#ff1053 100%);
  opacity: 0.8;
}
```

Comment: Thanks @user3176303, but the gradient goes behind the video instead of over it. I've updated my question with my code.

Comment: Kindly set of z-index and if you want to exactly code can you share on the  https://codepen.io.

Comment: Okay, I'll share it on CodePen. :)

Comment: Here's the link => https://codepen.io/cate-k/pen/wYZdae It looks different on my project though.

Comment: You want to like this - http://themenectar.com/demo/salient-corporate-2/

Comment: Yeah, that's the one, @user3176303.

Comment: I saw that you updated your Pen, thanks @user3176303! 